# Can I make a transformer based chatbot which is pretrained on some other dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, chatbot, huggingface-transformers, medical

I'm currently making a medical transformer chatbot from the tutorial from this page:

https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/05/transformer-chatbot-tutorial-with-tensorflow-2.html

I'm using a text corpus of medical questions/answers. When I train the model and test it, it just gives answers to questions relevant to medical domain. However, I want to create a conversational chatbot which can answer basic questions like 'How are you' and 'I need help'. Is there a way I can us some pretrained weights, then train the model on my medical dataset?
I'm pretty new to natural language processing domain so could really use some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: The answer is: Yes and no. There are infinite ways to discuss project solutions and methods but it won't fit in a slackoverflow answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General solution is to design some dialog template that you can fill with question answers. Then use the qa model to generate synthetic dataset. You should be able to use the generated data to train/finetune/setup your chatbot.
The rest is about important details in a project you got there!

Comment: Can you refer me any article or post that further explains this general solution? Thanks!

Comment: If you use Rasa for chatbot, you probably need your data in these formats: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu-training-data

Comment: I don't have a paper on this, but a master project i co-supervised was using relativly similar method: manually distilling conversation data into chat templates. Then generating variations by replacing synonyms etc.. http://semdial.org/anthology/papers/Z/Z20/Z20-4028/

Comment: If you get to extract real question/answers from the qa-datasets you can generate + templates for conversation you can generate a synthetic dataset and test on it. Then perhaps finetune it with real conversations...